# Как можно обратиться к элементу из списка условий для фильтра инфоблока в админке?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, битрикс

Делаю жесткий фильтр для пользователей по полю "Кто создал". Нужно что бы фильтр работал скрыто и пользователь не мог его отменить! Единственное что может сейчас сломать мой фильтр, так снятие галочки из списка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача такая, как можно обратиться к данному элемента списка чтобы скрыть его (тупо прописать `display: none;`данному элементу) ?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант скрыть 9ый пункт меню через CSS воспользовавшись свойством `li.menu-item:nth-child(9) { display: none; }`

Comment: а если выводиться список не через li, а через span, то тоже подойдет?

Comment: да, конечно, я для примера написал, смысл в :nth-child(номер элемента в списке); Костыль конечно... но это же битрикс..

Comment: спасибо большое заранее, буду пробывать сейчас))

Comment: все оказалось гораздо сложнее. Обращаюсь к классу bx-core-popup-menu-item - это класс span который выводит элемента списка, пробую сделать передачу стиля 9 элементу и не работает.
`bx-admin-prefix .bx-core-popup-menu: nth-child(9) {display: none;}` может что что я не понимаю или надо что то помощнее

Comment: Пробывал еще по другому. Есть `<div class="bx-core-popup-menu bx-core-popup-menu-bottom bx-core-popup-menu-level0 bx-core-popup-menu-no-icons"`   в котором находятся эти span, пробывал обратиться к нему:
`.bx-core-popup-menu .bx-core-popup-menu-bottom .bx-core-popup-menu-level0 .bx-core-popup-menu-no-icons span:nth-child(10) {display: none;}` Суть в том что я обращаюсь к диву что бы он передал  `{display: none;}` 10-ому span-у и тоже не работает

Comment: Вы можете привести полный пример разметки? Подскажу вам селектор.